# XPath Subset Selection

Tags: html, xml, xpath

I have the following XML (which is actually HTML):

```
<html>
    <h4>something</h4>
    <p>a</p>
    <p>b</p>
    <h4>otherthing</h4>
    <p>c</p>
</html>
```

Can a XPath selects the "p" nodes that are following siblings of the first "h4" node but not following siblings of second "h4" node (selecting "p" node a & b only)?

Comment: Good question (+1). See my answer for a solution using general XPath expression for node-set intersection and for checking if a node is not in a given node-set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My take

```
//p[preceding-sibling::h4[1] and not(preceding-sibling::h4[position() > 1])]
```

finds all p elements which are siblings of the first h4 but not siblings of any other h4 on the same axis

Alternative

```
//h4[1]/following-sibling::p[count(preceding-sibling::h4) = 1]
```

finds all following p element of the first h4 element that do have exactly one preceding h4 element

Comment: I think you could simplify your first answer into `/*/p[not(preceding-sibling::h4[2])]` and second answer into `/*/p[count(preceding-sibling::h4)=1]`.

Answer (score 3):

**Use**:

```
/*/h4[1]/following-sibling::p
            [not(count(preceding-sibling::* | /*/h4[2])
                =
                 count(preceding-sibling::*)
                 )
             ]
```

**More generally, the intersection of two nodesets `$ns1` and `$ns2` is** selected by:

```
$ns1[count(.|$ns2) = count($ns2)]
```

**The fact that a node $n is not in a node-set $ns1 is expressed by**:

```
not(count($n | $ns1) = count($ns1))
```

This is fundamental set theory and usage of the standard XPath `|` (union operator and `not()` function.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming no `<p>` preceding the first `<h4>`,

```
//h4[2]/preceding-sibling::p
```

Comment: it's not selecting the first h4's following siblings, but the second h4's preceding siblings, which is a difference, although it yields the correct result

Comment: @Gordon //h4[1]/following-sibling::p returns a b and c. Kenny's answer makes sense, but would also need to handle the case where there is only one h4 element.

Comment: @nonnb I didnt say it doesnt make sense. I am just saying, it's different from what was asked.