# Using XPath to find the first child of a specific grandparent?

Tags: xpath

I'm dealing with some gnarly HTML.  Here's a stylized example of the ancestry of a given element:

`/html/body/foo/bar/baz/quux/b`

I have a reference to `body` in my code and `b` is the context element for my XPath query. In the above example how do I find `foo`?  More descriptively, how do I find the first element in a given ancestry which is the child of another given element?  The elements between `body` and `b` are unknown and varied in type and depth at runtime.  I can do this outside of XPath by iterating over the ancestors from `b` until I get to `body` but I'm wondering if there's some XPath ancestor magic to find this relative reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Use**:

```
ancestor::body[1]/foo
```

this selects the element that is the first element child of `body` that is the first ancestor `body` of the context node.

**Even if you know that there are no nested `body` elements, the above is slightly more efficient than**:

```
ancestor::body/foo
```

because evaluating this last expression, *all* ancestors will be tested for being a `body`.

**UPDATE**:

In a comment the OP clarified:

> Well, I'm trying to find the intersection of the two sets (ancestors
>   of context node, children of body)

**In XPath 1.0 this is q direct substitution into the well-known Kayessian formula for node-set intersection**:

```
$ns1[count(.|$ns2) = count($ns2)]
```

**In this case we substitute `$ns1` with `ancestor::*` and $ns2 with `/*/body/*`**:

```
ancestor::*[count(. | /*/body/*) = count(/*/body/*)]
```

**In XPath 2.0 this is easier, using the `intersect` operator**:

```
ancestor::* intersect /*/body/*
```

Comment: Sorry for not being clear: foo, bar, baz and quux are dummy tags. In the document the position of foo among body's children is not known and this doesn't work. Do you have any suggestions about changing the phrasing of the question to help make this more clear?

Comment: Ack, sorry, I still wasn't clear.  I don't even know the tag name of foo, it could be anything.  I just have `body` and the context node and know that the context node is a descendant of `body` at some level (it could be immediate, it could be nested).

Comment: So while googling around I found one of your previous answers on this topic (http://stackoverflow.com/a/3591270/296239).  I've tried the xpath `/html/body/*[count(. | ancestor-or-self::*) = count(ancestor-or-self::*)]` and it returns a list equal to that of `/html/body/*`.  Doing independent checks on this xpath I can see that `/html/body/*` and `ancestor-or-self::*` are producing the right sets.  Any tips why they aren't going together?

Comment: @ldrg: If you don't know the name of the element you want select, how do you define what element must be selected? This is completely absent in the question. Do you really know what are you asking? And the question/answer linked from your prev. comment is about something *totally* different -- it is how to select a node-set that are between two given nodes -- not what you are asking for in this question.

Comment: Well, I'm trying to find the intersection of the two sets (ancestors of context node, children of `body`) which contains what I'm looking for.  I know it's in the xml, I know logically it's the intersection of the two sets, is there a way to get it via pure xpath?  Perhaps I just totally worded the question wrong.

Comment: @ldrg: OK, if that's what you want, this is quite different from what you are asking in the question -- it would be a good idea to edit the question. I have updated the answer and the update contains the solution to the problem you specified in your last comment.

Answer (score 2):

Without testing it, I would guess that `ancestor::body/*[1]` might do it.

Explanation: `ancestor::body` is the first `body` element along the `ancestor` 'axis', `/*` selects all of the children of that element, and `[1]` selects the first element of that list of children, which in this case is `foo`.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear: foo, bar, baz and quux are dummy tags.  In the document the position of foo among body's children is not known and this doesn't work.  Do you have any suggestions about changing the phrasing of the question to help make this more clear?